# Nativescript Vue - State updated but UI does not

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Im not sure if I am doing something wrong but from my understanding this Code should switch the Tabs on Bottom navigaton Selection

```
<template>
  <Page>
    <GridLayout rows="*, auto">
      <StackLayout class="page" backgroundColor="white" row="0">
        <Frame v-if="currentTab === 0">
          <Overview />
        </Frame>
        <GridLayout class="p-20" v-if="currentTab === 0">
          <Label
            class="h1 text-center"
            text="First tab"
            textWrap="true"
          ></Label>
        </GridLayout>
        <GridLayout class="p-20" v-if="currentTab === 2">
          <Label
            class="h1 text-center"
            text="Third tab"
            textWrap="true"
          ></Label>
        </GridLayout>
      </StackLayout>
      <MDBottomNavigationBar
        activeColor="blue"
        inactiveColor="grey"
        backgroundColor="white"
        @tabSelected="onBottomNavigationTabSelected"
        :titleVisibility="visibility"
        row="1"
      >
        <MDBottomNavigationTab title="Meine WG" icon="res://md_home" />
        <MDBottomNavigationTab title="Einkauf" icon="res://md_shopping" />
        <MDBottomNavigationTab title="Putzplan" icon="res://md_clean" />
        <MDBottomNavigationTab title="Kalender" icon="res://md_date" />
      </MDBottomNavigationBar>
    </GridLayout>
  </Page>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      visibility: 1,
      currentTab: 0,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    currentTab(val) {
      alert(val);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onBottomNavigationTabSelected(args) {
      this.currentTab = args.newIndex;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Instead when opening the `<Overview />` component is rendered, selecting a different Tab removes it but reselecting the Tab with the index 0 doesnt rerender anything, also the Grid Layout with condition `currentTab === 2` doesnt get rendered.

The alert I put in the watcher to check if the state updated fires, so I do not understand why the UI behaves so strange.

Comment: Have you tried using v-show instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to hide and display the Overview component depending on the tab that's selected, you can try moving the v-if to the Overview tag, i.e.: `<Overview v-if="currentTab === 0" />`. You should also remove the `<Frame>` tag.

The `<Frame>` tag is used for navigation, so you would typically set its contents using the $navigateTo() function.

If you intend to use the `<Frame>` for navigation, you need to make sure any components you navigate to (including Overview) have a `<Page>` tag as the root element within `<template>`.